# What is UITest.new_browser_session

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am very new to Ruby and am trying to understand below line:

```
$watir_browser = UITest.new_browser_session browser, profile
```

Comment: Why not just read the docs?

Comment: Looks like it's creating a `UITest` object, passing in a couple of parameters, and assigning to a global variable.  Are you actually using `watir` here?